# Google API OAuth 2 Error, MUST INCLUDE HTTPS

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

first time trying myself on scripting.
I created a script to access the youtube API and later upload a video; here is the beginning of the script:

```
import os
import time
import json
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


# Set the folder to monitor
folder_path = 'D:/test/'

# Set the interval for checking the folder (in seconds)
check_interval = 60

# Set the YouTube API credentials
client_secrets_file = 'client_secrets.json'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
api_service_name = 'youtube'
api_version = 'v3'

# Load the list of uploaded videos from a file
uploaded_videos_file = 'uploaded_videos.json'
if os.path.exists(uploaded_videos_file):
    with open(uploaded_videos_file, 'r') as f:
        uploaded_videos = json.load(f)
else:
    uploaded_videos = []


def get_authenticated_service():
    """Gets an authenticated YouTube API service."""
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
    flow.redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:8080'
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')
    print('Please go to this URL: {}'.format(authorization_url))
    authorization_response = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    return build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

Now when entering my authorization code i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadtoyoutube2.py", line 90, in <module>
    upload_video(video_file)
  File "uploadtoyoutube2.py", line 57, in upload_video
    youtube = get_authenticated_service()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uploadtoyoutube2.py", line 40, in get_authenticated_service
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 285, in fetch_token
    return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(self.client_config["token_uri"], **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 244, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_uri_response(
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\web_application.py", line 220, in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 272, in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise InsecureTransportError()
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InsecureTransportError: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.
```

I don't know where I am not using https. the redirect uri uses https, all urls appearing in the client_secrets file are using https as well. This is my first project so sorry for my lack of knowledge and me possibly missing crucial details and I hope someone can help! Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you running a http server on localhost?

Comment: Not that I know of.. I did netstat -ano and checked for connections using 80 or 8080 but there weren't any.
But mind you im really inexperienced so it is possible!